# Parse a shortcode differently based on on what it's nested in

Tags: filters, shortcode, conditional-content

Suppose we have two different sets of nested shortcodes, like this:

#### Apple version

- `[wrapper snack="apple"] Today I had a [flavor] snack... [/wrapper]`
- **Desired output:** My snack was quite HEALTHY today...

#### Donut Version

- `[wrapper snack="donut"] Today I had a  [flavor] snack... [/wrapper]`
- **Desired output:** My snack was quite FATTY today...

My question is: how can I parse the nested shortcode (`[flavor]`) differently depending on the shortcode it's nested in (i.e., based on `[wrapper]`'s snack attribute)? Please accept for the sake of the question that it's impossible/impractical to add an attribute to `[flavor]`.

In pseudo-code, it might work something like this:

```
function flavor_shortcode_handler ( $atts, $content ) {
    $wrapper = ??? // The value of the shortcode this is nested inside

    if ( $wrapper == 'apple' ) return 'HEALTHY';
    if ( $wrapper == 'donut' ) return 'FATTY';
}
```

I imagine there are a variety of ways to get the same effect by how we write `wrapper`'s handler function.

### Idea 1: Use a global variable

```
function wrapper_shortcode_handler ( $atts, $content ) {
     // After extracting the snack attribute...
     $GLOBALS['wrapper_value'] = $snack;
     return do_shortcode( $content );
}
```

### Idea 2: Find/replace the nested shortcode before processing it

```
function wrapper_shortcode_handler ( $atts, $content ) {
     // After extracting the snack attribute...
     $new_content = str_replace( '[flavor]', '[flavor wrapper="'.$snack.'"]', $content );
     return do_shortcode( $new_content );
}
```

Obviously the examples and solutions are oversimplified, but is there an alternative that would work better?

Answer (score 1):

Register a new shortcode handler depending on the attribute value:

```
function wrapper_shortcode_handler ( $atts, $content ) {

    if ( "apple" === $atts["snack"] )
        add_shortcode( "flavor", "healthy_callback" );

    if ( "donut" === $atts["snack"] )
        add_shortcode( "flavor", "fatty_callback" );

    return do_shortcode( $content );
}
```

See also [Execute shortcode only in another shortcode](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74503/execute-shortcode-only-in-another-shortcode)